# Restarting an if then statement

Tags: python, if-statement

like if I had in python.

```
choice1 = raw_input('John Blue Green')
if choice1 == 'A':
   print('blah')
elif choice1 == 'B':
   print('blahblah')
```

and someone enters B but its incorrect so I want it to go back and ask again.
How do I do that?
Beware,
I am a programming noob.

Comment: use: return; below print('blahblah')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically need to loop this. One example would be to put it in a endless loop and manually break it when the desired result is reached:

```
while True:
    choice1 = raw_input('John Blue Green')
    if choice1 == 'A':
        print('blah')
        break # <-- 'A' is okay, so we can get out of the loop then
    elif choice1 == 'B':
        print('blahblah')
```

Depending on your situation you can of course adjust the `True` in the loop condition to make it not endless but actually react on the user input. Then you wouldn’t need the `break`, but the loop would just naturally stop looping. But if you have multiple accepting input values, then it might be cleaner to still use breaks instead of having a huge loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try a while loop maybe, so you would get:

```
choice1 = ''
while (choice1 != 'A'):
    choice1 = raw_input('John Blue Green')
    if (choice1 == 'A'):
        print('blah')
    elif (choice1 == 'B'):
        print('blahblah')
```

And here is some explanation on while loops:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Comment: `while` is lowercase-only; and it’s usually discouraged to use parentheses around conditions for whiles and ifs. Also you are missing a `'` in the second condition.

Comment: Ah yeah, it's been a while since I fully used python.
The parentheses should work fine though, that's just a styling choice.

Comment: Sure, just wanted to mention it. Anyway, I’m the last person who will argue about *personal* styling preferences (for non-shared projects anyway)…

Answer (score 0):

you should put your code in a loop and ask for confirmation (or decide somehow decide according to your own logic) whether to quit the loop:

```
confirmation = 'n'
while (confirmation != 'y'):
  choice1 = raw_input('John Blue Green')
  if choice1 == 'A':
    print('blah')
  elif choice1 == 'B':
    print('blahblah')
  confirmation = raw_input('are you happy with the result?(y/n)')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
choice1 = raw_input('John Blue Green')
while(choice1 == 'B'):
    print "blahblah"
    choice1 = raw_input('John Blue Green')
print "blah"
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: Why it doesn't? It ask for an input, then while choice1 is 'B', it keeps asking until it choice changes.

Comment: Because I believe if `choice1` is `C`, you shouldn't print 'blah'.